# Dynamic method dispatching in Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

The following is the code snipplet regarding my doubt.

```
class A {
    void someMethod(A param) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class C extends A {
    void someMethod(C param) {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}

class DMD {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A ac = new C();
        C c = new C();
        ac.someMethod(c);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A
```

but I excepted the output as

```
C
```

Because I have allocated memory for `C`, and `A` is referring to `C`'s memory location, so if I call the method on the `A` reference which is pointing to `C`, and the argument is passed as `C` type, then I expect the `someMethod(C)` method should execute.

Can anyone please give me the proper reason for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have can't compile since C doesn't extend A.

Comment: This has nothing to do with regular expressions btw

Answer (score 3):

Method invocations on methods taking distinct argument types (overloading) are realized at compile time. (And this is your case)

If all 3 methods accepted argument of type A - i.e. method *overriding* was present, only then polymorphism would come into play and would trigger the method of `C` provided there is a inheritance relationship between A and C i.e. C extends A.

Answer (score 2):

The decision which method to use basically has two phases: first the overload resolution, then the method dispatch. Overload resolution happens at compile-time, method dispatch at runtime.

In this example the overload resolution decides that the overload `someMethod(A param)` should be used because that's the only overload of `someMethod` defined in class `A` (and the static type of `ac` is `A`).

At runtime it is decided which implementation of `someMethod(A param)` to use, but since there is only one implementation (`C.someMethod(C)` does not override `someMethod(A)` as `C` is more specific than `A`), `A.someMethod(A)` is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written will not successfully compile. You cannot say "A ac = new C();" because C does not extend A. If you claim to have run this and gotten output, you must have mis-copied something from your running code into this post.

If, for the sake of argument, your code really said "A ac = new A();", then your code still wouldn't run, because `A.someMethod` takes an `A`, not a `C`. The statement `ac.someMethod(c)` executes the function `A.someMethod`. `ac` is of type `A`, so executing any function against `ac` will get the function of that name from class `A`. Trying to pass a parameter of type `C` to a function declared to take a parameter of type `A` will not "switch" you to using a function from a different class that does take such a parameter. Overloading only works within a class.

Perhaps what you're thinking of is an example more like this:

```
class A {
    public void someMethod(A a) {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

    public void someMethod(B b) {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class Dmd {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.someMethod(b);
    }
}
```

This will output "B".

The difference here is that the class `A` has two versions of the function `someMethod`. One of them takes an `A`, one takes a `B`. When we call it with a `B`, we get the `B` version.

Do you see how this is different from your example? You are declaring three classes each with a function `someMethod`. Here we have one class with two functions both named `someMethod`. That's very different in Java.